# Are all isometric constant displacement maps bijective?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. An isometry is a distance preserving map. A constant displacement map is a function $f$ such that $d(x,f(x)=d(y,f(x))$ for all $x$ and $y$. I know that not all isometries are bijective. But are all maps that are both constant displacement and distance-preserving also bijective? I would like to see a proof or a counterexample. I have tried working on this problem but I have not succeeded in proving anything.

Comment: Can you find a non-bijective isometric constant displacement map from $\Bbb R_+$ to $\Bbb R_+$?

Comment: In addition to dfeuer's remark, there are noninjective constant displacement maps from real line union one point to itself.

Comment: @studiosu, the OP was asking specifically about constant displacement maps that are also isometries. An isometry in a *metric space* (as opposed to a pseudometric space) is always injective.

Comment: Oops, I did not see the distance preserving condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The map $x\mapsto x+1$ on the space $M=[0,\infty)$ preserves distances, and is constant-displacement, but is not onto. (Following dfeuer's hint).